# Azure. Kusto. Parse Json with date type field

Tags: azure, kql

I struggle with some strange behavior kusto query.

I logged json with field named date and ill try to get value from this field.
I made a little POC and got two diferent behavior.
When i called field as  Date  then the query executes fine. If I just rename it to date unfortunately I am not able to run the query.

Scenario 1.

`let T = datatable(MyString:string) [ '{"Date":"2023-03-05T00:00:00.0000000Z","hour_start":"10:00","hour_end":"21:00","option":"recent"}' ]; T  | project MyJson = parse_json(MyString) | extend Date_ = tostring(MyJson.Date)`

Scenario 2.

`let T = datatable(MyString:string) [ '{"date":"2023-03-05T00:00:00.0000000Z","hour_start":"10:00","hour_end":"21:00","option":"recent"}' ]; T  | project MyJson = parse_json(MyString) | extend Date_ = tostring(MyJson.date)`

How to handle with this query where fieldName equal date ?

Please see detailed descriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you hit a reserved word.

use `MyJson["date"]` (same goes for identifiers with spaces and/or special characters).

See [Identifier quoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#identifier-quoting)

```
let T = datatable(MyString:string) [ '{"date":"2023-03-05T00:00:00.0000000Z","hour_start":"10:00","hour_end":"21:00","option":"recent"}' ];
T 
| project MyJson = parse_json(MyString) 
| extend Date_ = tostring(MyJson["date"])
```

| MyJson | Date_ |
| --- | --- |
| {"date":"2023-03-05T00:00:00.0000000Z","hour_start":"10:00","hour_end":"21:00","option":"recent"} | 2023-03-05T00:00:00.0000000Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAz2OwQqCQBCG74LvMOxFhYrV6GJ06xR4ylMiYjqUIruyO0FSvXujS80MDPPPP8M3IEEOB2hr4rwOGGbTmUynbqldWgQFBC/BexSpSGSyXUuuXS5lutRGuriIlbjrh6ks1YbYG8/bn4iqnc9jJ%20mROq1YMNigIvEJoNz7Xg6%2094bR6B4bgmw6Wa2YbayNxarn4Q8XLU58Ev%20FI7NV7CPtkEN3WTjoMvoCd%20UG2OQAAAA=)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it :).
I knew there was a problem with it but I had no idea how to deal with it because I'm a beginner in kusto and I couldn't find such an example in the docs.

Thank you very much :).

Comment: See updated answer for doc reference (Identifier quoting)